# Cannot assign a value of type '[UIImage?]' to a value of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, tableview

I am trying to call images but getting error "Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'String'" I would be thankful for help.

```
 class flowerVC: UIViewController {
var label = ""
var pic = ""
var info = ""
@IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    label1.text = label
    label2.text = info
    image.image = UIImage(named: pic)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

---

the code on top is where the self.images and detailview.pic are defined, sorry if not I'm new in xcode.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.cost.text = flowers[indexPath.row]
    cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show" {
        let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let detailview : flowerVC = segue.destination as! flowerVC
        detailview.label = self.names[indexpath.row]
        detailview.info = self.flowers[indexpath.row]
        detailview.pic = self.images[indexpath.row] //Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'String'
```

}

Comment: The obvious issue is that detail view.pic is not defined as an UIImage, but instead as a string. How to correct it? More code is needed.

Comment: Please provide the code at the origin of your problem, i.e. the code in which `self.images` and `detailview.pic` are defined.

Answer (score -1):

Probably that  pic is String type from `detailview.pic.`

Comment: Yeah it was 3 am and i supposed it wa>> cannot assign value of type String to value of type UIImage so this answer doesnt stand. I will update it.